# base filtering engine fails to start - error 5 access denied. Server 2008 R2

Tags: networking, windows-server-2008-r2, windows-service, windows

We had a major server fault over the weekend where some hard drives and the mainboard's raid controller failed.
Mainboard and HDD's replaced - the Windows Server 2008 R2 is loading up, but many of the network applications cannot be access from the connected computers.
This IS NOT a DC, it DOES NOT perform DHCP or DNS, but it DOES provide dial-in VPN access for remote users.
The server can access the internet fine - because I can connect to it via TeamViewer - but there are a number of services that will not start since the hardware recovery.
Also - the Teamviewer application is generating a new ID every single time it is run, so that also makes me think there is an underlying network issue.

Initially, **DHCP client service**, **TCPIP NetBIOS helper**, **Network Location Awareness** and a few other services would not start.  After some registry changes to allow *SERVICE*, *LOCAL SERVICE* and *NETWORK SERVICE* permissions on a few of these problematic services; and adding *LOCAL SERVICE* and *NETWORK SERVICE* to the *Administrators* group; most of these services are now running, and some of the network capability is back.

However, none of the client computers can access the SQL database application we use and a number of other network apps...

It appears that the **Base Filtering Engine**, which is a dependent service for **Windows Firewall**, **Diagnostic Policy Service** and **Routing and Remote Access Service**, is failing to start despite my permissions changes in the registry and any other attempts to get it working.
All four of these services which are either *Automatic* or *Automatic (delayed)* are failing to start.

There's no malware or virus infections - so please, no suggestions about checking for these.

I've run the SFC /scannow procedure to check for file corruptions... there was nothing found.

I've gone through the DACL settings as discussed on http://blogs.technet.com/b/rspitz/archive/2010/09/19/quot-access-is-denied-quot-when-you-attempt-to-start-the-base-filtering-engine-service-after-upgrading-from-windows-server-2003-to-windows-server-2008-r2.aspx and none of the non-windows services are missing the specific entry referred to.

I'm at a loss as to what to try next.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: Describe the "...registry changes to allow SERVICE, LOCAL SERVICE and NETWORK SERVICE permissions..." you mention. It's unclear to me why there would be any changes necessary. This might be a clue to your Base Filtering Engine (BFE) problems. What gets logged in the Event Log when you try to start the BFE (either by BFE itself, or the Service Control Manager)?

Comment: I now have BFE starting!!!  The `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\BFE` key now has "everyone" set will full permissions.  When I look at another Win2k8r2 server with no issues, this permission level is not set, but it seems to have helped this problem server.  Now the only service I cannot get started is the **Diagnostic Policy Service**.  I notice that **Windows Firewall**, **BITS**, **Windows Update**, and **Routing and Remote Access** all need to be started manually despite the Automatic or Automatic (delayed) setting.