# Can't stop Base Filtering Engine service on Windows Server 2016 Essentials

Tags: windows-server-2016, windows-service, windows-server-essentials, quickbooks

According to [Quickbooks Help](https://help.quickbooks.intuit.com/en_US/kb/error-h101-h202-h303-or-h505-opening-your-company-file/000007008_en_US:SALESFORCE.modal), every time we restart our server (Server 2016 Essentials) we need to restart the Base Filtering Engine service. This procedure has always worked in the past for us. However, after the latest Windows Server updates install and reboot, we are unable to stop or restart the BFE service. It is currently running, but when attempting to stop it we get the following error:

```
"Windows could not stop the Base Filtering Engine service on Local Computer. Error 5: Access is Denied."
```

I have tried setting the permissions for the BFE registry key per recommendations found [across](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/sharepoint/en-US/d8e59632-fca9-4bbd-b748-881af144706a/access-denied-base-filter-engine?forum=winservergen) [the](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/networking/2011/06/14/the-windows-firewall-service-fails-to-start-registry-permissions/) [internet](https://serverfault.com/questions/638459/base-filtering-engine-fails-to-start-error-5-access-denied-server-2008-r2). However, those all seem to describe situations where the BFE service won't start. In my case, the service is running and I can't stop or restart it.

Is there something else I can try to get the service to stop?

Answer (score 0):

You have to disable Windows Defender through Group Policy. Then you will be able to stop the base filtering engine and scan the QB data files. Follow the following steps:

Run GPEdit (Edit Group Policy)
Computer Configuration
 Administrative Templates
  Windows Components
   Windows Defender
    Turn Off Windows Defender
     Set to Enable
     Apply 
     OK

Go to Services
Stop Base Filtering Engine Service
Yes to Stop Other Services
Stop Again if Necessary after error messages
Go to QB Database utility and scan data files in QB Directory
Start the following services
    Base Filtering Engine Service
    IPSec Policy Agent
    Windows Firewall
    IKE and Auth IPSec Keying Modules

Run GPEdit (Edit Group Policy)
Computer Configuration
 Administrative Templates
   Windows Components
    Windows Defender
     Turn Off Windows Defender
      Set to Disabled
      Apply 
      OK

Start Windows Defender Service